# how to sum of same id will put in a new column and show on each first row of that id?

Tags: mysql

i have table like below called text_book :

```
Ord_ID--- book_name--- amount--- reg_time
01    --- abc1      --- 100   --- 2020/4/22 09:00
01    --- abc2      ---  50   --- 2020/4/22 09:01
01    --- abc3      --- 200   --- 2020/4/22 09:02
02    --- abc1      --- 100   --- 2020/4/22 09:00
02    --- abc2      ---  50   --- 2020/4/22 09:01
|
|...
```

i want the output by sql like below:

```
Ord_ID--- book_name--- amount--- reg_time ---------Total
01    --- abc1      --- 100   --- 2020/4/22 09:00---350
01    --- abc2      ---  50   --- 2020/4/22 09:01
01    --- abc3      --- 200   --- 2020/4/22 09:02
02    --- abc1      --- 100   --- 2020/4/22 09:00---150
02    --- abc2      ---  50   --- 2020/4/22 09:01
|
|...
```

Comment: There is no apparent way of establishing first row.

Comment: Thanks ..
is it possible to show the sum amount in the last row of the particular ID?

Comment: You have edited so that time can establish first or last row. What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: thanks a lot...Then how will be MySQL queries?

Comment: And your version is?

Comment: Server version 10.2.12-MariaDB

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212240/discussion-between-rakib-and-p-salmon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First generate a row number , then join to a total then decide what to print on the basis of row number

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;

CREATE TABLE T (Ord_ID int, book_name varchar(10), amount int, reg_time datetime);
insert into t values
(01    , 'abc1'      , 100   , str_to_date('2020/04/22 09:00', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i')),
(01    , 'abc2'      ,  50   , str_to_date('2020/04/22 09:01', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i')),
(01    , 'abc3'      , 200   , str_to_date('2020/04/22 09:02', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i')),
(02    , 'abc1'      , 100   , str_to_date('2020/04/22 09:00', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i')),
(02    , 'abc2'      ,  50   , str_to_date('2020/04/22 09:01', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i'));

select a.ord_id,a.book_name,a.amount,a.reg_time,
         case when a.rn = 1 then a.total
         else '' 
         end as total
from
(
select t.*, s.total
         , row_number() over (partition by ord_id  order by book_name) rn
from t 
join
(select ord_id ,sum(amount) total from t group by ord_id) s on s.ord_id = t.ord_id
) a;

+--------+-----------+--------+---------------------+-------+
| ord_id | book_name | amount | reg_time            | total |
+--------+-----------+--------+---------------------+-------+
|      1 | abc1      |    100 | 2020-04-22 09:00:00 | 350   |
|      1 | abc2      |     50 | 2020-04-22 09:01:00 |       |
|      1 | abc3      |    200 | 2020-04-22 09:02:00 |       |
|      2 | abc1      |    100 | 2020-04-22 09:00:00 | 150   |
|      2 | abc2      |     50 | 2020-04-22 09:01:00 |       |
+--------+-----------+--------+---------------------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.002 sec)
```

Comment: Can not implement here...Where is the problem?.. My real envionment is :

SELECT RIGHT(textbook.t_reserve_a.ord_id,5), textbook.m_student.student_id,  textbook.t_reserve_b.book_name, textbook.t_reserve_b.amount, textbook.t_reserve_b.reg_time FROM textbook.m_student INNER JOIN textbook.t_reserve_a ON textbook.m_student.student_id=textbook.t_reserve_a.student_id 
INNER JOIN textbook.t_reserve_b ON textbook.t_reserve_a.ord_id=textbook.t_reserve_b.ord_id ORDER BY textbook.t_reserve_a.ord_id;

Comment: You should raise as a new question and include table definitions and sample data as text.